# ¿Cuál es la magia de este algoritmo?

Tags: javascript, operador

Estoy un poco confuso con un código de una respuesta de [`SO`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39173669/3866134).

> La pregunta en cuestión pide resolver una función que lea un array y
>   devuelva 1 en caso de que encuentre 4 ceros en posiciones
>   consecutivas.

Aquí está el código de una de las respuestas (el cual no se muy bien como interpretar) :

```js
function has0000(arr) {
    let c = 1;
    return +!arr.every( n => c = (c*2+!!n) & 0xF );
}

// Editado
// Equivalente
function has0000(arr) {
    let c = 1;
    return +!arr.every( n => {
      console.log('n', n, '; operación :', ((c*2+!!n) & 0xF).toString(2))
      c = (c*2+!!n) & 0xF;
      return c;
    } );
}


console.log('RESULTADO :', has0000([6, 7, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 4, 0, 0, 1]));
console.log('-------------');
console.log('RESULTADO :', has0000([6, 7, 5, 0, 0, 0, 3, 4, 0, 0, 1]));
```

¿Qué tipo de "magia" se esconde en esta operación?

```
c = (c*2+!!n) & 0xF;
```

Creo entender que en cada iteración sobrescribe el valor de c por `c*2` +- 1 (Dependiendo si el número es > 0) y lo compara con "0xF" que representa el número 15. 
Aún así no logro entender como consigue el resultado que se propone, según comenta el autor:

> Solo los 4 bits más recientes son retenidos: Cada iteración el
>   siguiente bit se desplaza desde la derecha, mientras que el que ocupa
>   la posición más a la izquierda se retira, siempre almacenando 4 bits.
>   Si el resultado se vuelve 0 en cualquier momento el bucle se para.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Notemos que:

- la operacion `a & 0xF` (bitwise AND) equivale a quedarse con los 4 bits menos significativos de `a`. Por lo tanto, en el código podemos pensar a `c` como un **string de 4 bits**
- `!!n` ([doble negación lógica](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784929/what-is-the-not-not-operator-in-javascript)) equivale a convertir el entero `n` a un booleano, con valor `true` si `n` es distinto de 0. Al sumar esto un entero (`+!!n`) el valor se convertirá a entero (0 o 1).
  O sea que `a + !!n` es lo mismo que `a + ( n != 0 ? 1 : 0)`.
- `c*2`, para un entero, equivale a correr los bits (shift) un lugar a la izquierda
- `c = (c*2+!!n) & 0xF` equivale entonces a "quedarse con los 3 bits menos significativos de `c` y concatenar (a la derecha) un nuevo bit `1` - salvo que `n` sea cero, en cuyo caso concatenamos un `0`.

La instrucción `c = (c*2+!!n) & 0xF` se ejecutará una vez para cada elemento del array; `n` será el valor del elemento, y `c` tendrá como valor inicial el valor de la iteración anterior.
La única manera de que `c` valga `0` en algún momento es, entonces, si el array tiene cuatro ceros consecutivos (lo cual "vaciará" el string `c`).

El método `arr.every` retorna `true` si la instrucción devuelve true en **todas** las iteraciones - lo cual sucederá en nuestro caso si `c` es distinto de cero en todas las iteraciones, es decir, si el array **no** tienen 4 ceros consecutivos.

Si (y solo si) el array tiene 4 ceros consecutivos, `c` valdrá cero en (al menos) una iteración, y `every` retornará `false`. El valor retornado se niega primero (para que retorne true en este caso) y se convierte a entero con `+!arr.every`

Comment: Gracias por la explicación !! :)